# SWIG C++/Python: inheritance proxy objects

Tags: python, c++, inheritance, swig, ownership

I have something like that in C++ files, that compose my SWIG module :

```
class CObject {
    public:
        void do() {
            // some treatments
        }
};
class Interface {
    public:
        void add(CObject* obj) {
            obj->do();
        }
};
```

In python code, that used my SWIG module, there is something like that :

```
from mySwigModule import Interface, CObject

class MyObj(CObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CObject, self).__init__()


inter = Interface()
inter.add(MyObj()) // ERROR
```

This code is very basic. The real one deals with larger objects.
But the problem is: when running Python code, something like that is printed :

```
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'Interface_add'.
Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    Interface::add(CObject *)
```

How can i explain to SWIG how cast the object in CObject ?

There is certainly something to do with typemaps, but i don't know exactly what.
I tried to add this in interface file, without success :

```
 %typemap(in) CObject * {
     if ((SWIG_ConvertPtr($input, (void **) &$1, $1_descriptor)) == -1) {
         $1 = (CObject *) $1;
      }
 }
```

The error returned at compilation is something like :

```
 error: macro "SWIG_ConvertPtr" requires 4 arguments, but only 3 given
 In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_Interface_add__SWIG_0(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
 error: ‘SWIG_ConvertPtr’ was not declared in this scope
```

In real code, Interface::add() is called with 2 arguments. Maybe typemaps need to specify types of others parameters ?

debian, python 3.2, SWIG 2.

EDIT: the real error is show.

Comment: I've had some problems in the past with Python deleting my SWIG objects. Can you try: `my_obj = MyObj()` then call `inter.add(my_obj)`.

Comment: After tests, this change nothing, even if i stock `my_obj` in the class attribute of the class that used `mySwigModule`. But, when i stock it in a global var, C++ code refuse the object, because it is not a CObject type : `NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'Interface_add'`

Comment: It's probably a typo, but this line seems erroneous in your .h: `void add(CObjects* obj)` there's an extra 's'.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Nop, the main problem is always here : how cast a python object A to a C++ object B, given A is a subclass of B ?  Sorry for confusion.

Comment: This should work, I think there must be something wrong in code not shown, such as .i, or command line args to SWIG. I would definitely not test it with a temporary, be sure to use a data member as suggested in MasterMind's first comment, you want to rule that out while trying other things. Did you trace through to check that `obj` pointer is not null in `Interface::add`?

Comment: It's totally exactly, there is a problem about pointers. I update the post. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `__init__` has an error. Try this:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(MyObj, self).__init__()
```

or even this:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
```

Complete test:

```swig
/* example.i */
%module example
%inline %{
class CObject { public: void do_it() {} };
class Interface { public: void add(CObject* obj) {obj->do_it();} };
%}
```

```python
# test.py
from example import Interface, CObject

class MyObj(CObject):
    def __init__(self): super(MyObj, self).__init__()

Interface().add(MyObj())
```

```
$ # build and test procedure
$ swig -o example_wrap.cc -python -c++ example.i
$ g++ -o example_wrap.os -c -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4 example_wrap.cc
$ g++ -o _example.so -shared example_wrap.os
$ python3 test.py 
$
```

Comment: Its terrible; thank you so much for that ! Total success. Thanks again !